# Partial background with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I am trying to achieve a partial background in my SwiftUI project. I have been fiddling with this for a while now but can't seem to get exactly what i am looking for. In the top of my view i have a bar chart, this has a blue background. Below i have a RoundedRectangle with two buttons. I want the background of the chart to continue to below the RoundedRectangle, and cut off half way. I result in either of the two following:

- 1; The size and color are correct, however it is stuck in the middle and i can't seem to get it to start at the top [result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LauPU.jpg)
- 2; The size and location are correct, but the color is not what i want. I want it to be fully blue until half and then cut off. [result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrMvo.jpg)

The code i used to get result 1 is the following:

```
                Vstack(Spacing: 0) {
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Welcome back")
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundStyle(Color.white)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Picker soon")
                        }
                        .padding()
                            
                        Chart {
                            ForEach(subjectAverages.sorted { $0.round > $1.round }, id:\.id_subject) { subjectAverage in
                                BarMark (
                                    x: .value("Vak", subjectAverage.code),
                                    y: .value("Gemiddelde score", subjectAverage.round)
                                )
                                .foregroundStyle(
                                    .linearGradient(
                                        colors: [.blue, .yellow],
                                        startPoint: .bottom,
                                        endPoint: .top
                                    )
                                )
                                .alignsMarkStylesWithPlotArea()
                                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16))
                                .annotation {
                                    Text("\(subjectAverage.round)%")
                                        .font(.caption)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(height: 200)
                        .chartYAxis(.hidden)
                        .chartXAxis {
                            AxisMarks(stroke: (StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 0)))
                        }
                        .padding()
                    }
                    .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.25))

                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        ZStack {
                            
                            Color.blue.opacity(0.25)
                                .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)
                            
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                                .fill(.white)
                                .frame(height: 75)
                                .clipped()
                                .padding()
                                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.5), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 8)
                            
                            HStack {
                                NavigationLink(destination: StartPracticeQuestionView()) {
                                    Text("Button 1")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                                        .background(Color.blue)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                                
                                NavigationLink(destination: StartExamView()) {
                                    Text("Button 2")
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
                                        .background(Color.blue)
                                        .cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                            }
                            .padding()
                        }
                    }
                }
```

For result 2 i switched the

```
                            Color.blue.opacity(0.25)
                                .frame(height: geometry.size.height / 2)
```

With:

```
LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue.opacity(0.25), .clear]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
```

I hope my question and explanation is clear. There is probably a simple solution to this, but i just haven't found it. Thanks for taking the time to read my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your layout without using `ZStack` in the following manner:

```
HStack {
    NavigationLink(destination: StartPracticeQuestionView()) {
        Text("Button 1")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
    NavigationLink(destination: StartExamView()) {
        Text("Button 2")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 150, height: 50)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}.padding()
.background(Color.white)
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
.shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.5), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 8)
.padding() //this controls the top padding that you were seeing as white
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.background {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Color.blue.opacity(0.25)
            .frame(height: (geometry.size.height / 2))
    }
}
```